# Migrate existing sqlite database to Room, where to put existing migration scripts?

Tags: android, database-migration, android-room

I have an existing sqlite database on version 3. My SqliteOpenHelper manages upgrading from v1 to 3. I'd like to migrate to Room. I understand making a new Room Migration to go from my current v3 to the new Roomified v4, but where do my existing migration scripts go?

If user upgrades app from v2 of the database straight to v4 of the database, Room will handle v3 to 4, but what handles v2 to 3?

I tried porting migration scripts into Room Migration objects, but they fail to run because no json schema exists (room was used on those schemas).

I tried keeping my old SqliteOpenHelper around and using it to upgrade from 1 to 3 before building the Room database. This works first run, but subsequent runs crash the SqliteOpenHelper saying it can't downgrade the db (Room successfully upgrades to v4, but open helper only knows about v3. Using it to ensure db upgraded to v3 causes it to try and downgrade)

Comment: What json schemas do you mean?

Comment: Room auto generates them for each DB version. Uses them to detect when schema changes occur, etc

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer, please let me know if it worked for you

Comment: yeah it does work at runtime. Room's migration tester is the only part that blows up due to missing json schema. So now just need to come up with an adapter so i can use my legacy scripts from existing tests and wrap them in Room migration's for Room to use at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you can move all your old migrations to Room's `Migration` objects, so in your case create all of : `Migration(1, 2), Migration(2, 3), Migration(3, 4)` migrations.
There are also a few things to know about:

- migrations will be executed lazily - when the first query is
  executed, not when Room instance is retrieved
- if your current version is 3 you will need to create migration to version 4, even empty, as you already noticed
- if you want to speed up the migration process, you can create direct Migrations like `Migration(1,4)`

Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PersistenceMigrationsSample/app/src/room3/java/com/example/android/persistence/migrations/UsersDatabase.java) which is well described in this [article](https://medium.com/google-developers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929) and let me know if you have any more questions.